# Setting cursor to default for elements with is-inactive class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouse-cursor

## Objective

Once the maximum number of players (two goalies, six defensemen, twelve forwards) in each of their categories have been chosen, the remaining players `picked` with the class `is-inactive` should been set to `cursor:default`

## Clarification of the problem

**All the players have the class `is-inactive` as a default,** and what I'm trying to do is trying to set `cursor: default` only after other players have been picked and have had their class switched to `is-active`.

**ie.** Two goalies are picked and now have the class of `is-active` and take the `cursor:pointer` behaviour on hover. There are a total of ten players in this category, the other eight goalies are `is-inactive` and should have the `cursor: default` behaviour.

## Problem

- I'm trying to switch the css for the cursor back to it's default, but even players with `is-inactive` still have the `cursor: pointer` on them

### style.css

```
.player {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
```

### index.html

```
<div class="player player--goalie year--1990">
  <div class="tooltip tooltip--tall">
    <p class="tooltip__name">Brian Elder</p>
    <p class="tooltip__hometown"><span>Hometown:</span> Oak Lake, Man.</p>
    <p class="tooltip__years"><span>Years Played:</span> 1992-1997</p>
    <div class="tooltip__stats--inline">
      <div class="stats__group stats--games">
        <p class="stats__header">GP</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--games">110</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--goalsag">
        <p class="stats__header">GA</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--goalsag">2.00</p>
        <p class="stats__number">3.12</p>
        <p class="stats__number">3.46</p>
        <p class="stats__number">2.70</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--savep">
        <p class="stats__header">SAV%</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--savep">.909</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.886</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.884</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.906</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--shutouts">
        <p class="stats__header">SO</p>
        <p class="stats__number">0</p>
        <p class="stats__number">0</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--shutouts">3</p>
        <p class="stats__number">2</p>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- tooltip__stats--inline -->
  </div> <!-- tooltip -->
  <div class="player__headshot player--elder">
    <div class="picked is-inactive"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  </div>
  <p class="player__name">Brian Elder</p>
  <p class="player__position">Goalie</p>
</div>
```

## scripts.js

```
/*-------------------------------------
COUNT SELECTED
--------------------------------------*/

function countSelected() {
    $(".player").on("click", function(){

        // Checks if the maximum number of players have been selected
        // If so, return false and then do nothing
        // If not, the class will toggle from `is-inactive` to `is-active`
        if ($(this).find(".picked.full").length > 0) return false;
        $(this).find(".picked").toggleClass("is-inactive is-active");

        // Count the number of players with stars
        var starredGoaltenders = $(".player--goalie").find(".picked.is-active").length;
        var starredDefencemen = $(".player--defencemen").find(".picked.is-active").length;
        var starredForwards = $(".player--forward").find(".picked.is-active").length;

        console.log(starredGoaltenders, starredDefencemen, starredForwards);

        // The number of starred players for each position cannot exceed the following numbers
        var maxGoaltenders = 2;
        var maxDefencemen = 6;
        var maxFowards = 12;

        // If the number of starred players hits its max, a class of `is-completed` is adding to the corresponding checkmark to indicate that the task has been completed
        if (starredGoaltenders === maxGoaltenders) {
            $(".checkmark--goalie").addClass("is-completed");
            $(".player--goalie").find(".picked").addClass("full");
        }

        if (starredDefencemen === maxDefencemen) {
            $(".checkmark--defencemen").addClass("is-completed");
            $(".player--defencemen").find(".picked").addClass("full");
        }

        if (starredForwards === maxFowards) {
            $(".checkmark--forward").addClass("is-completed");
            $(".player--forward").find(".picked").addClass("full");
        }

        // If all the conditions are met show the submit vote button
        if (starredGoaltenders === maxGoaltenders && starredDefencemen === maxDefencemen && starredForwards === maxFowards) {
            $(".btn--submit").show();
            $(".btn--submit").addClass("slideLeft");
        }
    });
} countSelected();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't mind a javascript solution, adding a class to the .is-inactive players after the first click of a player will provide a solution.

**EDIT** I was a little off with my first example because the .is-inactive and .is-active classes apply not to the .player objects but to descendants, however the following snippet provides the correct implementation:

**SECOND EDIT** After some discussion with the OP about his expectations, the following implementation better suits his needs.  I moved the .is-active and .is-inactive classes to the .player elements and then added the following lines to the click function:

```
$(".player").filter(".is-active").removeClass("not-picked");
$(".player").filter(".is-inactive").addClass("not-picked");
```

And this to the CSS:

```
.not-picked {
  cursor: default;
}
```

So that now whenever a player is clicked, it will select or deselect that player and the cursor will change unless the player-type (i.e. goalie) is full.

```js
/*-------------------------------------
COUNT SELECTED
--------------------------------------*/

function countSelected() {
    $(".player").on("click", function(){
        // Checks if the maximum number of players have been selected
        // If not, the class will toggle from `is-inactive` to `is-active`
        if ($(this).hasClass("full")) return false;
        $(this).toggleClass("is-inactive is-active");
        $(".player").filter(".is-active").removeClass("not-picked");
        $(".player").filter(".is-inactive").addClass("not-picked");
        // Count the number of players with stars
        var starredGoaltenders = $(".player--goalie").filter(".is-active").length;
        var starredDefencemen = $(".player--defencemen").filter(".is-active").length;
        var starredForwards = $(".player--forward").filter(".is-active").length;

        console.log(starredGoaltenders, starredDefencemen, starredForwards);

        // The number of starred players for each position cannot exceed the following numbers
        var maxGoaltenders = 2;
        var maxDefencemen = 6;
        var maxFowards = 12;

        // If the number of starred players hits its max, a class of `is-completed` is adding to the corresponding checkmark to indicate that the task has been completed
        if (starredGoaltenders === maxGoaltenders) {
            $(".checkmark--goalie").addClass("is-completed");
            $(".player--goalie").addClass("full");
        }

        if (starredDefencemen === maxDefencemen) {
            $(".checkmark--defencemen").addClass("is-completed");
            $(".player--defencemen").addClass("full");
        }

        if (starredForwards === maxFowards) {
            $(".checkmark--forward").addClass("is-completed");
            $(".player--forward").addClass("full");
        }

        // If all the conditions are met show the submit vote button
        if (starredGoaltenders === maxGoaltenders && starredDefencemen === maxDefencemen && starredForwards === maxFowards) {
            $(".btn--submit").show();
            $(".btn--submit").addClass("slideLeft");
        }
    });
} countSelected();
```

```css
.player {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

.not-picked {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="player player--goalie year--1990 is-inactive">
  <div class="tooltip tooltip--tall">
    <p class="tooltip__name">Brian Elder</p>
    <p class="tooltip__hometown"><span>Hometown:</span> Oak Lake, Man.</p>
    <p class="tooltip__years"><span>Years Played:</span> 1992-1997</p>
    <div class="tooltip__stats--inline">
      <div class="stats__group stats--games">
        <p class="stats__header">GP</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--games">110</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--goalsag">
        <p class="stats__header">GA</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--goalsag">2.00</p>
        <p class="stats__number">3.12</p>
        <p class="stats__number">3.46</p>
        <p class="stats__number">2.70</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--savep">
        <p class="stats__header">SAV%</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--savep">.909</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.886</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.884</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.906</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--shutouts">
        <p class="stats__header">SO</p>
        <p class="stats__number">0</p>
        <p class="stats__number">0</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--shutouts">3</p>
        <p class="stats__number">2</p>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- tooltip__stats--inline -->
  </div> <!-- tooltip -->
  <div class="player__headshot player--elder">
    <div><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  </div>
  <p class="player__name">Brian Elder</p>
  <p class="player__position">Goalie</p>
</div>

<div class="player player--defencemen year--1990 is-inactive">
  <div class="tooltip tooltip--tall">
    <p class="tooltip__name">Brian Elder</p>
    <p class="tooltip__hometown"><span>Hometown:</span> Oak Lake, Man.</p>
    <p class="tooltip__years"><span>Years Played:</span> 1992-1997</p>
    <div class="tooltip__stats--inline">
      <div class="stats__group stats--games">
        <p class="stats__header">GP</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--games">110</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--goalsag">
        <p class="stats__header">GA</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--goalsag">2.00</p>
        <p class="stats__number">3.12</p>
        <p class="stats__number">3.46</p>
        <p class="stats__number">2.70</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--savep">
        <p class="stats__header">SAV%</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--savep">.909</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.886</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.884</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.906</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--shutouts">
        <p class="stats__header">SO</p>
        <p class="stats__number">0</p>
        <p class="stats__number">0</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--shutouts">3</p>
        <p class="stats__number">2</p>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- tooltip__stats--inline -->
  </div> <!-- tooltip -->
  <div class="player__headshot player--elder">
    <div><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  </div>
  <p class="player__name">Brian Elder</p>
  <p class="player__position">Goalie</p>
</div>

<div class="player player--goalie year--1990 is-inactive">
  <div class="tooltip tooltip--tall">
    <p class="tooltip__name">Brian Elder</p>
    <p class="tooltip__hometown"><span>Hometown:</span> Oak Lake, Man.</p>
    <p class="tooltip__years"><span>Years Played:</span> 1992-1997</p>
    <div class="tooltip__stats--inline">
      <div class="stats__group stats--games">
        <p class="stats__header">GP</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--games">110</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--goalsag">
        <p class="stats__header">GA</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--goalsag">2.00</p>
        <p class="stats__number">3.12</p>
        <p class="stats__number">3.46</p>
        <p class="stats__number">2.70</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--savep">
        <p class="stats__header">SAV%</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--savep">.909</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.886</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.884</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.906</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--shutouts">
        <p class="stats__header">SO</p>
        <p class="stats__number">0</p>
        <p class="stats__number">0</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--shutouts">3</p>
        <p class="stats__number">2</p>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- tooltip__stats--inline -->
  </div> <!-- tooltip -->
  <div class="player__headshot player--elder">
    <div><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  </div>
  <p class="player__name">Brian Elder</p>
  <p class="player__position">Goalie</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post what the full snippet should look like. Right now, your solution is not working.

Comment: If you could elaborate more how you came to this solution that would be great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120629/discussion-between-andrew-nguyen-and-cameron637).

Answer (score 0):

You can select elements with multiple classes using `.class1.class2`. Try adding below code at the end of your CSS.

```
.player .is-active.picked {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Note:** It's better to avoid `-` in class names. Instead of `is-inactive` use `isInactive` or `is_inactive`.

```css
.player {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
}
.player.is-inactive {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="player is-inactive player--goalie year--1990">
  <div class="tooltip tooltip--tall">
    <p class="tooltip__name">Brian Elder</p>
    <p class="tooltip__hometown"><span>Hometown:</span> Oak Lake, Man.</p>
    <p class="tooltip__years"><span>Years Played:</span> 1992-1997</p>
    <div class="tooltip__stats--inline">
      <div class="stats__group stats--games">
        <p class="stats__header">GP</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--games">110</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--goalsag">
        <p class="stats__header">GA</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--goalsag">2.00</p>
        <p class="stats__number">3.12</p>
        <p class="stats__number">3.46</p>
        <p class="stats__number">2.70</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--savep">
        <p class="stats__header">SAV%</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--savep">.909</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.886</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.884</p>
        <p class="stats__number">.906</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stats__group stats--shutouts">
        <p class="stats__header">SO</p>
        <p class="stats__number">0</p>
        <p class="stats__number">0</p>
        <p class="stats__number stats__number--shutouts">3</p>
        <p class="stats__number">2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- tooltip__stats--inline -->
  </div>
  <!-- tooltip -->
  <div class="player__headshot player--elder">
    <div class="picked is-inactive"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="player__name">Brian Elder</p>
  <p class="player__position">Goalie</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added a point of clarification in the original question. I have tried `player.is-inactive` in my css to `cursor:default` but since all players have this class in the beginning, this is unfortunately not the solution.