# Add text to input only if div has class `is-active`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, for-loop

## Problem

- Players that have not been selected, ie. do not have a class of `picked.is-active` should not be added to any of the input fields when they are clicked on
- The maximum number of players that be be picked from each category is 2 out of 4 goalies, 6 of 15 defencemen and 12 out of 31 forwards.

### Update #3

Added link to the Github repo here: https://github.com/onlyandrewn/wheatkings

### Update #2

Added the snippet, which shows how the `is-inactive` and the `is-active` classes are being toggled.

### Update #1 -

**I've removed the second snippet which may be causing some confusion**

This Javascript snippet below grabs the name of the player clicked and then puts it into an input field, if it has a class of `picked.is-active`. However, let's say you've selected two goalies already, but then click on the two remaining goalies in that category when are unselected (have the default class `in-active`) **those unselected players still get added to the inputs, which is not what we want.**

---

### scripts.js - This snippet, which needs fixing, currently adds player name to input field even if max number players in specific category has been reached

```
$(".player").on("click", function(){
    var playerNames = [];
    $("input:text").each(function(i, t) { playerNames.push(t.value) });

    if ($(this).find("picked.is-active")) {
        var playerName = $(this).find(".player__name").html();
        var index = playerNames.indexOf(playerName);

        if(index == -1) // add player
            $("input:text:eq(" + playerNames.indexOf("") + ")").val(playerName);
        else // remove player
            $("input:text:eq(" + index + ")").val("");
    } else {
        $("input").val("");
    }
});
```

### scripts.js (How `is-inactive` and `is-active` classes are toggled)

```
$(".btn--random").on("click", function() {

    // CHECK THESE NUMBERS
    var goalies_array = getRandomNumbers(1, 4, 2);
    var defensemen_array = getRandomNumbers(5, 19, 6);
    var forwards_array = getRandomNumbers(20, 50, 12);

    $(".goalies").text(goalies_array.join(","));
    $(".defensemen").text(defensemen_array.join(","));
    $(".forwards").text(forwards_array.join(","));

    var players_array = goalies_array.concat(defensemen_array).concat(forwards_array);

    // Add the class `is-active` based on the numbers generated
    var player = $(".player");
    $(".is-active").removeClass("is-active").addClass("is-inactive");


    $.each(players_array, function(index, value) {
      var player_index = value - 1; // Subtract one based on zero-indexing
      player.eq(player_index).find(".is-inactive").removeClass("is-inactive").addClass("is-active");
  });
});

function getRandomNumbers(start, end, howMany) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = start, j = 0; i <= end; j++, i++)
        arr[j] = i
    arr.sort(function() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) - 1)
    });

    return arr.splice(0, howMany)
}
```

### index.html (Form snippet)

```
    <form id="form">
        <input type="text" name="p1"  id="p1">
        <input type="text" name="p2"  id="p2">
        <input type="text" name="p3"  id="p3">
        <input type="text" name="p4"  id="p4">
        <input type="text" name="p5"  id="p5">
        <input type="text" name="p6"  id="p6">
        <input type="text" name="p7"  id="p7">
        <input type="text" name="p8"  id="p8">
        <input type="text" name="p9"  id="p9">
        <input type="text" name="p10" id="p10">
        <input type="text" name="p11" id="p11">
        <input type="text" name="p12" id="p12">
        <input type="text" name="p13" id="p13">
        <input type="text" name="p14" id="p14">
        <input type="text" name="p15" id="p15">
        <input type="text" name="p16" id="p16">
        <input type="text" name="p17" id="p17">
        <input type="text" name="p18" id="p18">
        <input type="text" name="p19" id="p19">
        <input type="text" name="p20" id="p20">

        <button class="btn btn--submit" type="submit"><img src="src/img/ballot-alt.png" class="image--ballot">Submit Vote</button>
    </form>
```

### index.html (Player snippet)

```
        <div class="player player--forward year--2000 year--2010">
            <div class="tooltip">
                <p class="tooltip__name">Mark Stone</p>
                <p class="tooltip__hometown"><span>Hometown:</span> Winnipeg, Man.</p>
                <p class="tooltip__years"><span>Years Played:</span> 2008-2012</p>
                <div class="tooltip__stats--inline">

                    <div class="stats__group stats--games">
                        <p class="stats__header">GP</p>
                        <p class="stats__number stats__number--games">232</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="stats__group stats--goals">
                        <p class="stats__header">G</p>
                        <p class="stats__number stats__number--goals">106</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="stats__group stats--assists">
                        <p class="stats__header">A</p>
                        <p class="stats__number stats__number--assists">190</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="stats__group stats--points">
                        <p class="stats__header">Pts</p>
                        <p class="stats__number stats__number--points">296</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="stats__group stats--penalties">
                        <p class="stats__header">Pim</p>
                        <p class="stats__number stats__number--penalties">102</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="player__headshot player--mstone">
                <div class="picked is-inactive"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            </div>
            <p class="player__name">Mark Stone</p>
            <p class="player__position">Forward</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. The two snippets shown both add a click listener to the elements with class `player`. So they will run at the same time...but you first need to count the selected ones and only then try to add to input field, right?

Comment: I've removed the second snippet which may be causing some confusion. 

This first snippet grabs the name of the player clicked and then puts it into an input field, if it has a class of `picked.is-active`. However, let's say you've selected two goalies already, but then click on the two remaining goalies in that category when are unselected (have the default class `in-active`) those unselected players still get added to the inputs, which is not what we want

Comment: @fmilani Does that help at all?

Comment: Andrew, I've noticed something that may be the problem:

In your if clause `if ($(this).find("picked.is-active"))`, you're testing the return of jquery's [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/), which, according to the docs, returns a jquery collection, which is always truthy. Maybe you should change to `if ($(this).find("picked.is-active").length > 0)`

Comment: @fmilani That may be close, however adding `.length > 0` to that part makes all names not show up on click. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know. I'm still confused about how player can become "active". In your html snippet there's only one div with class `picked` and it has `is-inactive`. If you run your jquery code on this snippet, the length of `($(this).find("picked.is-active")` will indeed be 0. Can you create a codepen reproducing your problem?

Comment: @fmilani Adding the new snippet that shows how the `is-inactive` and `is-active` classes are toggled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122146/discussion-between-andrew-nguyen-and-fmilani).

Comment: @fmilani Let me know your thoughts, I'm going to send a link to the Github repo in the chat

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `.hasClass()`? As in `if ($(this.find("picked")).hasClass("is-active")) { ... }` *spitballin' on my mobile*..

Comment: @Dom Tried adding `.hasClass("is-active")` but when you click the player their name doesn't show up. I've posted a link to the Github repo: https://github.com/onlyandrewn/wheatkings

Comment: @Dom Any thoughts about what it might be?

Comment: @AndrewNguyen these is no constraint enforcing for maximum player count in each category while picking them in your code. also why are you clearing all input field if the clicked player is not "picked.is-active", though your checking will be always truthy as fmilani said?

Comment: @SufianSaory I'm open to any suggestion at this point to solve the problem.

Comment: please give us the all the position names. so you want to clear all selection if clicked player is not  "picked.is-active", right?

Comment: @Sufian Saory There are three positions: goalie, defenceman and forward. I don't want any player from those positions added to any of the inputs if that maximum number of that category has been reached.

Comment: @SufianSaory I've posted a link to the Github repo as well

Comment: I'm confused about your question now after seeing you have asked this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823862/setting-cursor-to-default-for-elements-with-is-inactive-class).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122304/discussion-between-andrew-nguyen-and-sufian-saory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing app state into dom/html element is not a good way to implement business. you should have really used data objects to hold app states. however following will enforce max count constraint for each category, assuming your player names are unique.

```
(function () {
    var maxCounts = {
        forward: 12,
        defenceman: 6,
        goalie: 2
    };

    var getSelectePlayerNames = function () {
        var names = [];
        $("input:text").each(function (i, t) {
            t.value && names.push(t.value);
        });

        return names;
    };
    var getPlayerPositionCounts = function (players) {
        var $players = $('.player');
        var positions = [];
        $.each(players, function (i, player) {
            positions.push($players.find(".player__name:contains('" + player + "')").next().text().toLowerCase());
        });

        return positions.reduce(function (memo, val) {
            memo[val]++;
            return memo;
        }, { forward: 0, defenceman: 0, goalie: 0 });
    };

    $(".player").on("click", function () {
        var $el = $(this);

        var playerName = $el.find(".player__name").text();
        var selectedPlayerNames = getSelectePlayerNames();
        var index = selectedPlayerNames.indexOf(playerName);
        if (index > -1) {
            $("input:text:eq(" + index + ")").val("");

            return;
        }

        if (!$el.find(".picked.is-active").length) {
            return;
        }

        var playerPosition = $el.find(".player__position").text().toLowerCase();
        var selectedPositionCounts = getPlayerPositionCounts(selectedPlayerNames);
        if (selectedPositionCounts[playerPosition] < maxCounts[playerPosition]) {
            $("input:text:eq(" + selectedPlayerNames.length + ")").val(playerName);
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Will this replace parts of my code or just be added to it?

Comment: Which part will it replace as there are two snippets of Javascript that I posted

Comment: the first snippet.

Comment: Right now, when I remove the first snippet and put in yours, the names of the players do not appear in the input fields.

Comment: This is what my scripts file looks like currently: https://gist.github.com/onlyandrewn/482c7aa0299c0c21f7f8d810e8dbac78

Comment: I don't see my code, you only commented your snippet. you need to replace your snippet...

Comment: I updated the gist, but the names are still not appearing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122321/discussion-between-sufian-saory-and-andrew-nguyen).